# Self password rotation - Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift cluster. One user can rotate his own password using below command:

```
testcluster=> select current_user;
 current_user
--------------
 u003
(1 row)

testcluster=> alter user u003 with password 'Newpassword123#';
ALTER USER
```

How to stop this self password rotation. It must be rotated by super user only.
Is there any way to achive this ?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to change user permissions? It's not clear what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Grice,  I have connected cluster as user "u003" and resetting own password. I would like to prevent this action from end user. It must be rotated always by super user. Any alternate way to achive this ?

Comment: What is your use-case for not wanting to let them change passwords themselves?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL allows users to change their own passwords.

See: [ALTER USER documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-alteruser.html)

Therefore, you cannot prevent users changing their own password.